# How to track an object with deformations in a sequence of images in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, detection, matching

I am currently trying to make a program in Matlab that detects an object in an image, and track it in a sequence of images.

In the matching algorithm, I have tried comparing area, perimeter and major axis length of the objects. This works when the objects maintain the same shape during the tracking time (it can move or rotate). However, my goal is to use this program on satellite images, where I want to track ice. The problem is that the ice floes does not maintain the exact same shape. I has some deformations.

Do you have any suggestions for a different approach to do this, which is invariant to deformations?

In my current program, I load each image and make them binary. Then, to find the properties of each object in each image, I run this code on the binary representation of the images:

```
% Find object properties
[clust,numb] = bwlabel(image, 8);
area = regionprops(clust,'Area');
s = regionprops(clust, {'Centroid'});
measurements = regionprops(clust,'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');
theta = regionprops(clust,'orientation');
perimeter = regionprops(clust,'Perimeter');

% Store centroids in matrix
centroids = zeros(numb,2);
for n=1:numb
    centroids(n,1)=s(n).Centroid(1);
    centroids(n,2)=s(n).Centroid(2);
end

% Store other properties in matrix (Order: area, majoraxis, minoraxis,
% orientation, perimeter)
properties = zeros(numb, 6);
for m=1:numb
    properties(m,1)=area(m).Area;
    properties(m,2)=measurements(m).MajorAxisLength;
    properties(m,3)=measurements(m).MinorAxisLength;
    properties(m,4)=theta(m).Orientation;
    properties(m,5)=perimeter(m).Perimeter;
end
```

I then use the properties stored when I compare the objects in the images.

My example images are:

[Test images](http://i57.tinypic.com/35n0b2t.jpg)

which looks like this after they are processed (made binary and all objects removed except the object I want to track):

[Processed images](http://i61.tinypic.com/2e2mgz5.jpg)

Sorry for using collages and not the original images. I did not have enough reputation to post all images.

Comment: There is no such thing as a tracking algorithm that is invariant to any kind of deformation, simply because it is way too broad. You have to specify what you mean by deformation: affine transformation ? Dilatation / Erosion ? Small deformations ? Please provide some sample images.

Comment: I have provided some sample images now.

Answer (score 2):

Problems like this are usually only tractable if you have some *a priori* knowledge of the system in question. You'll have to dig this up from your domain knowledge (unless there's an icefloes.stackoverflow.com) but we can make a naive first order approach for the purposes of seeing how to use it to develop a tracking algorithm.

So let's say that the deformation is gradual and the motion of the blocks is continuous. In that case you could extract the shape of a given block of ice in one frame and use it as the kernel for a correlation search in the local spatial region in the next frame. Your result will give you the centroid of the new location and you can then use that to extract the new shape to correlate with the next frame. The gradual deformations will result in imperfect correlations but using a new shape each iteration should allow you to keep tracking.

What if the deformations aren't gradual? Well perhaps the block stays the same shape and then suddenly cleaves into two (seems likely). Then you can track the block through the frames where it stays the same shape but when the block cleaves (I'm guessing this happens on a timescale less than the frame interval) the tracking will break. But if you've stored the trajectory of the block over the previous n frames you could extrapolate the path and then look in the expected spot for new pieces.

If you're tracking multiple blocks they should all follow roughly similar trajectories - the appropriate current vector in the sea I suppose - and you could perhaps also use these trajectories to interpolate spatially to see where a cleft block might end up.

Your problem differs from some similar imaging problems in that the blocks aren't going to disappear (I assume, apologies if this is not the case) so you know that your block is somewhere, even if it's in pieces. If you can identify more than one method of tracking them then perform all of them and vote on the results - that can be surprisingly effective, especially where you have two or more indiviaully weak results.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to do a correlation search in the local spatial region? I have edited my original question and added some example images.

Comment: The Mathworks website has some exceptional documentation, you can find examples of correlation and many other techniques there http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-an-image-using-normalized-cross-correlation.html

Comment: To make this a 'local' correlation search I just mean that rather than searching the whole of your image you would restrict the area to the region near to your match.